# functions: Error from emulator. Error occurred while parsing your function triggers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm testing firebase functions locally in my existing project in typescript. When i run following command, i always get typeerror even though i can upload it to firebase project. the error always occured after typescript compile to js

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
>       at Object. (C:\Users\phone\Desktop\VMS\mynewvm_functions\functions\lib\email\index.js:8:52)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\phone\Desktop\VMS\mynewvm_functions\functions\lib\index.js:19:15)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
const accountname = functions.config().emailaccount.username;
const accountpassword = functions.config().emailaccount.password;
/* smtp configuration */
```

I already set emailaccount in my project, below is my code.

```
firebase functions:config:set emailaccount.username="email@domain.com" 
emailaccount.password="mypassword"
```

Please note that it is working fine when uploaded to firebase functions but it's not when serving locally. what can i do to make it work locally?

**Finally, I just replace all my credentials with actual values instead of getting from firebase config. And I cd to functions folder and type `'npm start'`. it look like when i run `'firebase serve --only functions'`, it doesn't apply with recent changes so give me the same error until I type `'npm start'` which will run tsc and firebase shell, stop it (ctrl+c) then type `'firebase serve --only functions'` again. Fyi, I created my current firebase functions project using firebase cli and typescript.**

```
firebase cli - 3.18.4
firebase functions - ^1.0.1
firebase admin - 5.12.0
@google-cloud/storage - 1.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing for long period of time, I decided to put username, password and tokens directly in my functions for local testing although I don't really like this idea and I change back to functions.config().. when i deploy to firebase. Thanks for @Frank for answers

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in config parameter called `emailaccount`, so it seems you defined it yourself.

The local environment does not automatically contain these variables. You will actually have to define them in a file called `runtimeconfig.json`. An easy way to do that is shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#install_and_configure_the_cloud_functions_shell):

```
cd functions
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```

Comment: I've been trying to make it work for a day. I still have no idea why it doesn't work based on the examples.